# How do I handle UV hand-painted stuff on glass-like materials?

Tags: materials, uv

[image][image: Highlighted in blue is what i want to change]

[image: This should be the end result]

I want to change the transparent-looking canopy detonation lines (highlighted in blue) to white, like in the last image, but i want to keep their bump/indent thing visible. I drew them on by projecting the UV from top view, exporting it to a painting app, and using the edited finished png as the image texture. But it didn't turn out the way i wanted, can someone help me? Thanks in advance. (first pic is what it looks like, i obviously disabled the Canopy layer before putting it in blender, but it's visible here)

Comment: Hi :). Hi, how does the image texture look like? Could be as simple as inverting the color...

Comment: Just edited it now

Comment: Hey :). It looks like it would be a lot easier to change the det. cord lines inside your painting app, no? :)

Comment: Nope. No change, no matter what colour i picked.